# How do I change merchant sku using jet.com api

Tags: api, rest, jet.com-apis

I am newbie to jet.com api. Earlier I have worked in amazon api now i have a task of working with jet.com api. However I have a simple query that can we change merchant sku using jet api.

I have also read jet.com api documents but could find anything regarding changing merchant sku in jet.com api. I guess there must be somebody who knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem as im woking on jet.com since last two years, have communicated to jet.com many time.

Jet.com just provided archive method to hold products.
[Jet.com Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200520230002/https://developer.jet.com/docs/merchant-sku-archive)

There is no method defined to delete or update merchant sku once it is uploaded to jet.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your Merchant Sku 
Then there is no direct method unlike Walmart

1) First of all, you need to send an archive request for that particular product whose SKU you want to change

2) Now all you have to do is to upload a new product with the desired SKU 
and that product will be listed on Jet with changed Merchant SKU

Answer (score 0):

Currently jet don't have such feature, if you want to change SKU you need to archive the older SKUs(products) and again upload the new updated one over jet.com